# Is there a limit while completing find that bitizen objective?

Tags: tiny-tower

Some times I take more than 1 minute to find a bitizen objective. So I tried just pressing on every floor from top to bottom to see if I could find s/he easier. However I could have sworn I just ran out of guesses to where s/he was as I don't recall a message popping up or receiving the bux reward. So is there some sort of guess limit while searching for a bitizen objective?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no sort of time limit as to the number of guesses you make trying to find the target Bitizen. The almost-certain cause of not receiving the bux is that you pressed the X on the bottom right of the screen while performing the task. To make the long explanation short, there is no limit.